# How to put to the Map<Integer, Category> all values of List<Category> with key being taken from Category object itself with getId() using Stream API?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I use a loop to iterate through the list of categories, and for each category object, get its id using the `getId()` method and use it as the key to put the category object into the map. Here is an example code snippet:

```
Map<Integer, Category> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
List<Category> categoryList = // get the list of categories from somewhere

for (Category category : categoryList) {
    int categoryId = category.getId();
    categoryMap.put(categoryId, category);
}
```

This code creates a new `HashMap` called `categoryMap`, and then iterates through the `categoryList` using a for-each loop. For each `Category` object in the list, it gets the id using `getId()`, and then puts the `Category` object into the map using the id as the key.

After this loop completes, `categoryMap` will contain all of the categories from `categoryList`, with their ids as the keys.

But how to use the same with Stream API? And if I want to concat 2 `List`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `Collectors.toMap()` method to collect the elements from both lists into a single map, where the key is taken from the `getId()` method of each `Category` object. Here is an example code snippet:

```
List<Category> categoryList1 = // get the first list of categories from somewhere
List<Category> categoryList2 = // get the second list of categories from somewhere

Map<Integer, Category> categoryMap = Stream.concat(categoryList1.stream(), categoryList2.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Category::getId, Function.identity()));
```

This code concatenates the two lists using `Stream.concat()`, and then uses `Collectors.toMap()` to collect the elements from both lists into a single map. The first argument to `toMap()` is a function that extracts the key from each `Category` object (in this case, `Category::getId`), and the second argument is a function that returns the corresponding `Category` object (in this case, `Function.identity()`).

After this code executes, `categoryMap` will contain all of the categories from both lists, with their ids as the keys. If there are any duplicate ids, an exception will be thrown. To handle duplicates, you can provide a merge function as a third argument to `toMap()`.